# How to set environment variable for BACI compiler and interpreter?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, environment-variables

I have installed executable files for [BACI](http://inside.mines.edu/~tcamp/baci/baci_index.html#Using) compiler and interpreter in my Ubuntu system.

But now every time I have to compile my **.cm file** I have to go to the program folder and run **./bacc** and **./bainterp**.

Can anyone tell me how to set environment variables for these programs, so that I can use them like by simple typing **bacc** / **bainterp** from any directory (just like we use gcc)?

Comment: Thanks for finding a duplicate question for this! But I guess the answer is not what I asked for. I am still confused where is my answer out of any of the responses posted there? How to use **bacc** as a command in terminal?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate to me; maybe I don't understand. If you add the program folder to your path, you can run `bacc` and `bainterp` without needing to provide the full path or switching to the directory to run them as relative paths

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I have tried. That didn't work. If this helps to answer my question, then I want to draw an analogy between this with the Java Compiler and interpreter - Suppose you have tar out a java package in linux. then how would you set the path for **java** and **javac** commands to use them universally?

Comment: You put them on your path, that's how it works. Run `which java` in your terminal and you'll get the absolute path. Then run `echo $PATH` and you'll see a colon-delimited set of paths, which will include the directory `java` is in. Any executable in any of those directories will be runnable just using its name

Comment: Okay! I have got `echo $PATH` correct, but then nothing works. I have rechecked it with the directory. the command just doesn't run. But it runs from its current directory.

Comment: Are you just running `bacc`? Don't do `./bacc`, that's telling it to look for `bacc` in the current directory. If you run `bacc` by itself it will search your path in order

Comment: I am not doing that, I understand ./ means current path. `bacc` is not getting executed at the very first place! This is something super weird.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what the problem is, but I reopened the question. Might want to add an error message or something